# solr how can I check which query parser is called?

Tags: solr

I am wondering if there is a way to check/debug which query parser is called in Solr? I have added a custom query parser and at the same time I want to use "edismax" ranking. I ended up using "qt" parameter to pick "edismax" ranking up and "defType" parameter to pick up a query parser but it doesn't look like it is doing what I am expecting. It seems like my custom query parser isn't called at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a [`debugQuery=true`](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/CommonQueryParameters#debugQuery) in your query string to view how solr computes the scores and everything. It should have the different handlers it uses to compute the scores also.